# How to use Camera functionality in the react native for windows universal app

Tags: javascript, windows, react-native

I'm using react native for developing product for our company and I want to use camera functionality for windows universal application using react native.Please suggest me ,I'm new to this technology.

Comment: Maybe take a look at Google results like [this one](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/use-the-ios-camera-in-your-react-native-mobile-app/) first?

Answer (score 0):

To use a camera you can use this module: https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera

But i advise you to rather use this one which also allows you to give to the user the possibility to look for a file directly in the gallery

https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker

Comment: Does it work for windows applications?they have mentioned support for ios and android only.

Comment: I have the same question. Please let if you were able to achieve this. Thanks